# Kotlin JetPack Composable call in Java Activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have some figma designs from which I have loaded UI using Relay Plugin and Here is my Auto Generated Home.kt file.

```
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp

fun Home(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    // other function parameters
) {
    // Use the 'modifier' parameter wherever needed
    Box(
        modifier = modifier.then(padding(16.dp))
    ) {
        // Content of the home screen
    }
}
```

I want to load this view from my MainActivity which is in **Java** (I can not switch to Kotlin due to some reasons).
In doing so I am not able to figure out what to pass as `Modifier` object.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier;
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Padding;
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ComposeView composeView = findViewById(R.id.compose_view);
composition.setContent(() -> {
    Modifier modifier = Modifier.padding(new Padding(16));
    HomeKt.Home(
        modifier, /// WHAT TO PASS HERE ///
        // other function arguments
    );
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your Composable needs a @Composable annotation, secondly you don't have to pass a Modifier object to a Composable when calling it. You instantiate the Modifier object and set its properties at any point you like inside the Composable function. If you want to apply it the way you are doing so in the example this can be done:

```
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp

@Composable
fun Home(
    // other function parameters
) {
    val myModifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp)
        //other modifier parameters
    // Use the 'modifier' parameter wherever needed
    Box(
        modifier = myModifier
    ) {
        // Content of the home screen
    }
}
```

Your Java Activity should also look like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ComposeView composeView = findViewById(R.id.compose_view);
        composeView.setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.[Your choice here]);
        composeView.setContent{
    HomeKt.Home(
        // other function arguments
    );
});
}
```

Note that I set a ViewCompositionStrategy. This is very important when calling a Composable from a View based layout. It makes sure the Composable is tied to the lifecycle of the ViewGroup it is joining and is properly garbage collected when the Activity is destroyed.